# Model not updating after REST API call

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

I'm new to AngularJS and have been playing around with it to get to grips with it. I've been getting to grips with `$scope` within a controller and how its used as the context between the view and the model. I'm also getting to grips with Promises and async web calls.

However, I've reworked an incredibly simple project to use `this` instead of `$scope` within the controller and not pass in the `$scope` object.

However, where I am making an async call to fetch a JSON file to load the variable `usdToForeignRates`, the view never seems to update. All the other properties work. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

NOTE: I can get the view to update, if I change `this.usdToForeignRates` to be `$scope.usdToForeignRate`s, pass in the scope to the controller and then just change `index.html` to reference `usdToForeignRates` rather than `invoice.usdToForeignRates`.

controllers.js:-

```
var financeApp = angular.module('financeApp', []);
financeApp.controller('invoiceController', ['$http', function($http) {
this.qty = 1;
this.cost = 2;
this.inCurr = 'EUR';
this.currencies = ['USD', 'EUR', 'CNY'];
this.usdToForeignRates = [];
this.counter = 1;

loadRates();
function loadRates(){
    $http.get('rates/rates.json').then(function(rates)
    {
        this.usdToForeignRates = rates.data;
    });};

this.add = function () {
    this.counter = this.counter + 1;
};

this.getRate = function getRate(curr){
    return this.usdToForeignRates[curr];
};

this.total = function total(outCurr) {
    var result = this.qty * this.cost * this.usdToForeignRates[outCurr] / this.usdToForeignRates[$scope.inCurr];
    return result;
};
this.pay = function pay() {
    window.alert("Paid!");
};
}]);
```

index.html:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controllers.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Currency Service</title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="financeApp" ng-controller="invoiceController as invoice">
<div>
    <select ng-model="invoice.inCurr">
        <option ng-repeat="c in invoice.currencies">{{c}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="c in invoice.currencies">{{c + ' ' + getRate(c) + 'rate'}}</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="r in invoice.usdToForeignRates">{{r}}</li>
</ul>
<button ng-click="invoice.add()">Add</button>
<div ng-model="invoice.counter">{{invoice.counter}}</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This in the `then` function is the `http` promise context. You need a reference to the controller `'this'`. Try

```
var self = this;

function loadRates(){
    $http.get('rates/rates.json').then(function(rates)
    {
        self.usdToForeignRates = rates.data;
    });};
```

Comment: @BigBytes Glad I was bale to help, please mark this question as answered, thanks.